# Why does a ClickOnce installer promt permissions for .NET Client Profile

Tags: clickonce

I use [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) to deploy a small [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application. In publish parameters I set:

> Is avaliable offline.

In preprequisites I choose ".NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile" and "Windows Installer 3.1" + Download the components from the vendors. So, when I publish my application I get folder `app.publish` which contains setup.exe, *.application and folder application files.

But I have one question: 
When I try to install this application from setup.exe it always prompt with "MICROSOFT SOFTWARE SUPPLEMENTAL LICENSE TERMS" even if the target computer has installed a full version of .NET Framework 3.5 on it. After the user clicks *Argree*, it install something for a few seconds (3-5) and then start application installation process.

Is it normal?

I thought if .NET Framework 3.5 FULL version installed on the target computer then setup.exe have to start the application installation process...